# how can i have mysql.jar.index file in Jboss as7 com/mysql module

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-seam

I try to add new datasource using mysql connection from my application. I copy the h2 module then edit the module.xml content for mysql ones and add msyql.jar but im missing mysql.jar.index file in it. How can i have that jar.index file? Is that auto-gen? Can somebody pls help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! This will automatically generated by jboss. All you need to do is to add the module in jboss-deployment-structure.xml under WEB-INF (for .war) and under META-INF (for .ear).